# Recursively determining if a sequence is nondecreasing

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I want to use recursion here but my code is not fully correct. It is correct for some of the test cases. Help me where I'm wrong. I have to return recursive statement. Basically, I don't want to expand my code.

```
def nondecreasing(l):
  if l==[] or len(l) == 1:
    return(True)
  else:
    return(nondecreasing(l[1:-1]) if (l[1]<=l[2]) else False)
```

This code should check if the list is non-decreasing or not. A list is a non-decreasing if each element is at least as big as the preceding one. For instance `[]`, `[7]`, `[8,8,11]` and `[3,19,44,44,63,89]` are non-decreasing, while `[3,18,4]` and `[23,14,3,14,3,23]` are not.

The longer nondecreasing test case fails:

```
>>> nondecreasing([3,19,44,44,63,89])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in nondecreasing
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in nondecreasing
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in nondecreasing
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Which test cases fail?

Comment: This code should check if the list is non-decreasing or not. A list is a non-decreasing if each element is at least as big as the preceding one. For instance [], [7], [8,8,11] and [3,19,44,44,63,89] are non-decreasing, while [3,18,4] and [23,14,3,14,3,23] are not.

Comment: I've moved your comment to the question, in future please [edit] your question to add clarifications like that. You still don't have a [MCVE] however; please add a test case that shows what goes wrong and what output you expected instead. Include the full traceback for errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing two things wrong:

- You seem to assume Python indexing is 1-based. It's not, you are ignoring the value of `l[0]`. This also causes an issue with trying to access `l[2]`; that index doesn't exist when your list only contains 2 elements.

  ```
  >>> def nondecreasing(l):
  ...   if l==[] or len(l) == 1:
  ...     return(True)
  ...   else:
  ...     return(nondecreasing(l[1:-1]) if (l[1]<=l[2]) else False)
  ...
  >>> nondecreasing([1, 2])
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<stdin>", line 5, in nondecreasing
  IndexError: list index out of range
  ```
- You are ignoring the last value of the list when recursing; slicing to `[...:-1]` *removes* the last element, causing you to fail to detect a single last decreasing value:

  ```
  >>> nondecreasing([1, 2, 3, 4, 0])
  True
  ```

The following code corrects both errors:

```
def nondecreasing(l):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return True
    return nondecreasing(l[1:]) if l[0] <= l[1] else False
```

The `l[1:]` slice copies all elements except the first one.

Personally, I'd probably not use the conditional expression on the last line. The following is a little clearer:

```
def nondecreasing(l):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return True
    if l[0] > l[1]:
        return False
    return nondecreasing(l[1:])
```

Demo:

```
>>> def nondecreasing(l):
...     if len(l) < 2:
...         return True
...     if l[0] > l[1]:
...         return False
...     return nondecreasing(l[1:])
...
>>> nondecreasing([])
True
>>> nondecreasing([7])
True
>>> nondecreasing([8, 8, 11])
True
>>> nondecreasing([3, 19, 44, 44, 63, 89])
True
>>> nondecreasing([3, 18, 4])
False
>>> nondecreasing([23, 14, 3, 14, 3, 23])
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be

```
def nondecreasing(l):
  if len(l) <= 1:
    return True
  else:
    # the l[1] <= l[2] should be l[0] <= l[1], and l[1:-1] should be l[1:]
    return nondecreasing(l[1:]) if (l[0] <= l[1]) else False
```